# Почему когда я переключаюсь на ветку там появляется один и тот же файл?

Tags: git

Странное поведение в том, что у меня есть 2 ветки А и Б. Я сейчас на ветке Б, сделал коммит, все чисто. Переключаюсь на ветку А, ничего не делаю и просто переключаюсь обратно на ветку Б и у меня почему то в Unstage файлах появляется бинарный файл

```
/TV_Python/OPP/pretrainedModel/hao28-pose600000.npz
```

и если я делаю reset для этого файла, то это не помагает, он все равно остается.

Мне приходиться делать `git rm --cached -r .`, потом `reset` и все чисто.

Но почему каждый раз когда я возвращаюсь на эту ветку я получаю этот файл обратно?

Comment: возможна, используемая Вами IDE сама его генерирует.

Comment: @KoVadim так я не использую ide. Я переключаю ветки в GitExtention...

Comment: [git lfs](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/removing-files-from-git-large-file-storage). ну и заодно смотрите документацию к той приблуде, которую используете (gitextension или как вы её там назвали).